# How to hook and use WH_GETMESSAGE in AutoIt

Tags: hook, autoit, getmessage

Can someone give an example on how to hook in WH_GETMESSAGE into AutoIt to look for all system/app window messages on the desktop, and do something if a window is moved, and how to store the handle from the window that sent the message?

Comment: Have you tried searching in the [AutoIt Forum](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/)? There should be good examples over there.

Comment: @JohannesThomasMeyer, He's tried [asking](http://autoitscript.com/forum/topic/142321-fire-event-on-window-creationresizemoveclose/#entry1001755) at the AutoIt forums already.